# Explanation of picking an orthogonal array in the Taguchi method

Tags: experiment-design

I'm working on my thesis and I am trying to lower the amount of runs I need to do in an experiment so I thought I'd use the Taguchi method, however I don't understand how to use the [selector table](https://controls.engin.umich.edu/wiki/images/5/52/Selector.jpg). I've been over and over how this is supposed to work and I still don't think I'm doing it correctly. I have a 3^k method where k = 5.

My question stems from the fact that a teacher told me I could (should) use an L27 to have the interactions of 4 out of the 5 factors and I can't figure out how he thought of that given that, as I understand it, I should just be able to match the number of factors to my levels and that would give me my new array (L18) but apparently that's not the best for me to do.

Comment: Can you post the design matrices involved?

Answer (score 1):

I think that your professor is counting the interactions as separate to your 5 variables. This means that instead of having k = 5, with the inclusion of the interactions between 4 of your variables, k = 11.

I hope that helps!